# Syntax for writing to a SQL Server table from SPSS

Tags: sql, sql-server, spss

I just had an ODBC connection created between a SQL Server database and SPSS.  I see a lot of threads about importing data FROM SQL Server into SPSS, but I am looking for syntax for writing TO the SQL Server database from SPSS.

Can anyone provide an example of an insert or update statement do to this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate example syntax by using the wizard at File > Export to Database.  Or look at SAVE TRANSLATE /TYPE=ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

This is way kludgy, but you might be able to do this by installing pypyodbc, an odbc library for python, and then creating the records from within python.
The trick is to [download pypyodbc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypyodbc/) and then deposit the file in SPSS python library folder (mine is C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\22\Python\Lib). From there, you can import pypyodbc and execute sql statements from within a syntax file.